# Dask eror - min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: dask

I'm trying to use Dask to handle a reasonably large dataset but I keep getting

> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

when I try to run .describe().compute()

I have confirmed the Describe works in normal Pandas with the same dataset so it must be dask related.

Here is the line I'm using:
inpFile = dd.read_csv(fPath, sep='\t', error_bad_lines= False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

and the full error is:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 inpFile.describe().compute()
>         2 #inpFile2.describe()
>
> /home/badrul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py
>   in describe(self, split_every)    1306         num =
>   self._get_numeric_data()    1307 
>   -> 1308         stats = [num.count(split_every=split_every),    1309                  num.mean(split_every=split_every),    1310
>   num.std(split_every=split_every),
>
> /home/badrul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py
>   in count(self, axis, split_every)    1191
>   token=token, split_every=split_every)    1192             if
>   isinstance(self, DataFrame):
>   -> 1193                 result.divisions = (min(self.columns), max(self.columns))    1194             return result    1195
>
> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
>
> Although it doesn't run for very long so I suspect it's not loading.
>   The error then comes when I do: inpFile.describe().compute()

Comment: Can you post the output of `df.dtypes`? Or just check if all of your dtypes are `object` columns? There may be a bug in dask.dataframe.describe that can't handle all non-numeric columns.

Comment: Yep here is what I get:

user_000001                                   object
2009-05-04T23:08:57Z                          object
f1b1cf71-bd35-4e99-8624-24a6e15f133a          object
Deep Dish                                     object
Unnamed: 4                                    object
Im Famous (Pacha Ibiza)-09-28-2007           object
dtype: object

The file I'm working with is this:
http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~ocelma/MusicRecommendationDataset/lastfm-1K.html

Comment: Ok so I'm finding this command doesn't seem to work at all with even 1 row of made up data, all numeric. E.g. 1,2,3,4 (I tried switching from tab separated to comma separated to see if that made a difference too)

Comment: I opened https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2326 to track this. FYI dtypes are for an entire column, so changing just one row won't fix anything.